# How to get a 3D point in my space with Yaw, Pitch and Roll and len

Tags: c++, math, physics, game-engine

i need to calculate a 3d point in my world space when i have roll pitch , yaw , len.

need a function like this return for me a 3dpoint :

```
Get3DpointFrom_yaw_pitch_roll(yaw,pitch,roll,len)
```

Thanks !

i try this code but the problem is when yaw value is 0 the y will set zero !

```
 float x=0,y=0,z=0,r=30;float theta=0; float phi=0; 

 theta=-Camera_Yaw*3.1415/180; 

 phi=(3.1415/2)-(-Camera_Pitch*3.1415/180); 

 x = r*sin(theta)*cos(phi); 
 y = r*sin(theta)*sin(phi); 
 z = r*cos(theta);
```

Comment: [Trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) - math works, it really does!

Comment: my mind is how to calculate destination 3d point.for exam : x= sin(pitch ) * cos(yaw) ...

Comment: SO is not really a place for home work or exam tutoring…

Comment: it's not home work. i need it to calculate ray casting !  i have my weapon roll pitch yaw and need a to find destination point (where my weapon is looking )!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have spherical coordinates, the transformation is simply given by

```
x = r*sin(theta)*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(theta)*sin(phi)
z = r*cos(theta)
```

I'm not into flight business, but if I understand Wikipedia correctly, then `theta = yaw` and `phi = pi/2-pitch`. The roll angle on the other hand, is not needed, because if you look for a point, then you can roll it around along its axis as much as you want, it won't change it's coordinates (different story for a rigid body, of course).

Comment: When you change the pitch, clearly phi changes as well and so does sin(phi) and henceforth y.

Comment: Maybe you've defined your axis differently?

Comment: i think the formula is false. when my yaw is 0 then my y value will set 0 automatic!!!!!!! is this true ??? please look on formula when yaw is 0 and pitch is 20:
 y=30*sin(0)*sin(20) 
 y=30*(0)*(0.3420) !! 
 y=0 !!!!